# Automatically add a new record to a linked form when a new record is created in the master form

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, database-design

First, this forum has been invaluable in getting started with Access. Everyone here is amazing.
I've found answers to every question I've had but this one is stumping me.

I have a form with a linked form embedded inside.
The master form is for new technical cases ("Cases") and the other is for action plans that need to be completed regarding that case ("Action Plans"). I want to have the form setup so that when you first create a new record in Cases (or you've populated any field in the case) that a new entry will be added to Action Plans which will state that a new case has been opened. Basically just tracking the first action on the case, which is the establishment of the case itself.

I've found a few VB ways of doing something similar and watched a few videos but nothing seems to be matching my specific use case. I feel like this should be simple but I'm completely stuck.

I'm open to whatever workflow is easiest, but I'm basically looking for it to make this first record in Action Plans as soon as the new record is created in Cases. I could have a dedicated button to create that first record, whatever works. Any ideas?

[What the form looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddCpr.png)

Comment: If just stateing new case opened, why add record to ActionPlan? Statement is already done by the new Cases record.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple way you could deal with this.  Probably the simplest and most adaptable I've found is define a class with a Public Event.  In my application start up create an instance of that object, then in the method that Updates your data, raise that event and Finally, in your 2nd form have an event handler listening for that event and trigger your data update

```
Public Class AppEvent
Public Event DataUpdate(ByVal eventMessage as String)
'EventMessage Could be used for reporting to end user or flow control.  Use it however or add additional params
End Class
```

Then in ApplicationEvents.vb

```
Dim AppEvents as New AppEvent
```

Now in your DataUpdate method you can access that object and raise the event

```
My.Application.AppEvents.DataUpdate("Update Message")
```

In your second form I would declare local memeber for the AppEvents, using WithEvents and set it in the Constructor method and add the event handler to refresh your data

```
WithEvents eventlistner as AppEvent
Public Sub New()
   eventListner = My.Application.AppEvents
End Sub

Private Sub DataUpdated() Handles eventListner.DataUpdate
'Do you data refresh here
End sub
```

I'm sure their are tidier ways to do it using things like INotifiable, but this works for me

Comment: OK, I feel really dumb, but I have no idea how to do any of that. Maybe I'll just have users manually create those entries, lol. Thank you for the suggestion though!